# i have a code snippet in mysql which is showing error

Tags: mysql

```
select student_id, student_name, count(student_department) over (partition by student_department) as department_total 
from students;
```

this is the command i gave to mysql but it is showing Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '(partition by student_department) as department_total from
> students LIMIT 100' at line 1 Error Code: ER_PARSE_ERROR

tried to write a command in mysql

Comment: Provide the mysql query here.

Comment: Seems like you are using mysql 5.7 or below, the `over() partition by` available on mysql 8

Answer (score -1):

Based on the given MySQL query. I do some assumptions about the query. Here is an example.

```html
SELECT s.student_id, s.student_name, d.department_total
FROM students s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT student_department, COUNT(*) AS department_total
    FROM students
    GROUP BY student_department
) d ON s.student_department = d.student_department;
```

Hope this will help you. Let me know this will work or not.